# Using non-default packages in setup.py

Tags: python, installation, pip

I made a Python repository template and I've gotten it to work with `python setup.py` but not `pip install` because `pip install` doesn't take into account installed packages that are not default to Python when it runs into import statements. It turns out this is critical to my template because it uses another library I wrote as part of the setup.py script, and this library imports other libraries.

I install and import this library as part of setup.py itself, but again this doesn't work when running "pip install" which means any library using my template will not work as a pip package. Is there not any way to install and use other libraries *during installation* while using `pip install`?

Example error when running `pip install <library>`:

```
      import git
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: pyproject.toml supports declaring build depends. Setup.py and setup.cfg are the old style tooling that aren't well supported going forward. You can override the build-backend entrypoint as described here https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/build_meta.html On the other hand, you should really evaluate if your script actually needs custom setup tooling, or if you can get away with a more standardized packaging structure.

Comment: @flakes Thanks! I'll see how well pyproject.toml is picked up by pip install. I'm using another Python template that uses setup.py as a starting point, but I suppose I can have both present.

Comment: I would stick with one option to simplify the process. `pyproject.toml` is the industry standard going forwards and is quite compatible with recent versions of `pip`. I would opt to use pyproject.toml instead of whatever template that still using deprecated tooling.